# Doctrine ORM - arithmetic operations

Tags: symfony, orm

I want to divide a single value by 100 inside the CONCAT function in orm query. The code looks like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT((u.value/100), 'foobar') FROM AcmeBundle:User u
```

However it doesn't work - division symbol is undefined. The same applies to `DIVIDE()` function. How am I supposed to achieve this?

Comment: Did you check with my answer below?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try doing something like this?

Link :- http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/cookbook/aggregate-fields.html#using-dql

```
$dql = "SELECT CONCAT((u.value/100), 'foobar') FROM AcmeBundle:User u ";
$balance = $em->createQuery($dql)              
          ->getSingleScalarResult();
```

Hope this helps,

Cheers!